# How to get the columns names orderly acorrding to the list in python using for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a problem. I have a list which contains data frame column names it should match with the data frame if the name is matched it should get appended in a new list. I wrote code which does that but the names are getting appended according to the sequence of data frame but not according to list. How do I do that?

```
Input: 
col_lst = ['hj','pl','fgc','bc','drt']
df=
   abc bc  fgc drt  
0  0   q   d  3  
1  0   g   t  1  
2  0   a   g  4 
3  0   d   c  5  
4  0   h   b  6
```

My code:

```
lst=[]
for i in df:
       for j in col_lst:
              if i in j:
                  lst.append(j)
```

I get the Ouput like this `lst =['bc','fgc','drt']`

what I want is `lst = ['fgc ','bc','drt']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do like this give the name as listwise see following stuff

```
col_lst = ['hj','pl','fgc','bc','drt']
lst=[]
for j in col_lst: 
   if j in df.columns: 
       lst.append(j) 
print(lst)
```

output will be

```
['fgc ','bc','drt']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following list comprehension.  The key is that you iterate through your col_lst (not your df) and check to see if a particular column in is you df with an if statement.

```
result = [col for col in col_lst if col in df]
```